# Unable to add versioning_configuration for multiple aws s3 in terraform version 4.5.0

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

Trying to create multiple AWS s3 buckets using Terraform with the below-provided code.
Provider Version: 4.5.0

Tried without `count` function and with `for_each` function as well

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "public_bucket" {
  count = "${length(var.public_bucket_names)}"
  bucket = "${var.public_bucket_names[count.index]}"
  # acceleration_status = var.public_bucket_acceleration

  tags = {
    ProjectName        = "${var.project_name}"
    Environment        = "${var.env_suffix}"
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "public_bucket_versioning" {

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.public_bucket[count.index].id 

  versioning_configuration {
    status =   "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Facing below error

```
 Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
│ 
│   on modules/S3-Public/s3-public.tf line 24, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "public_bucket_versioning":
│   24:   bucket = aws_s3_bucket.public_bucket[count.index].id 
│ 
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code creates multiple S3 buckets, but only attempts to create a single bucket versioning configuration. You are referencing a `count` variable inside the bucket versioning resource, but you haven't declared a `count` attribute for that resource yet.

You need to declare `count` on the bucket versioning resource, just like you did for the s3 bucket resource.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "public_bucket_versioning" {
  count = "${length(var.public_bucket_names)}"
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.public_bucket[count.index].id 

  versioning_configuration {
    status =   "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Comment: Then use it in there I guess? Your question is not clear. How would you use a simple count index value to enable versioning?

Comment: What if I need to use the variable for versioning_configuration with count index

Comment: Please stop spamming multiple people with notifications by adding different `@` comments and then deleting them. If you spent that time adding clarity to your question you might get an answer without having to spam people with notifications.